# as3 - tweenlite X coordinate approaches and gets slower

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I have a rookie problem with Tweenlite. As I am playing around with it, I noticed when my animation approaches closer to its coordinate "**x:100** It begins to gradually slow down. How do I make it so that from the time the object begins moving, to the very end, the speeds stays the same. Also when the object first begins movement, it starts out on a regular speed, and gradually becomes slower as its making its way.

> TweenLite.to(my_box.anotherBoxInside, 5, {x:100, ease:Linear.easeNone,
>   onStart:myFunction, onComplete:myFunctionn});

Comment: There's no problem with the script, **Linear.easeNone** is what TweenLite suggest in their tutorial: https://greensock.com/docs/Easing/Linear

Answer (score 0):

Change ease parameter to: Power0.easeNone

```
TweenLite.to(my_box.anotherBoxInside, 5, {x:100, ease:Power0.easeNone, onStart:myFunction, onComplete:myFunctionn});
```

Comment: That's not the point actually, **Linear.easeNone** might be deprecated and kept for backward compatibility reasons only, but it should work exactly the same as **Power0.easeNone**.